# Highcharts column Point Click

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Hello I have already asked a question on Highcharts Point Click not working. Further to that what I have found is my click function works in google chrome but not in IE 8. Can you please help me with this? I am not getting any responses on my earlier question hence I am posting this again -

Below is my code -

```
var columnoptions = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Exposure Details - Column Chart'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Exposure'
                    }
                },              
                plotOptions: {  
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            alert ('here');
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        },
                series: []
            };
```

and below is the function which draws column chart -

function displayColumnChart(){

```
     columnoptions.series = [];
     columnoptions.xAxis.categories = [];            
      var seriesOptions = {
                    name: 'chart',
                    data: [],                       

                };
     for(index = 0; index < categoryArray.length; index++){

         columnoptions.xAxis.categories.push(categoryArray[index]);

         seriesOptions.data.push(valueArray[index]);        

     }      

     columnoptions.series.push(seriesOptions); 
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart(columnoptions);
   }
```

Is it because the way I am dynamically creating this chart? Please guide me regarding this.  I am getting error - Object doesnt support this property or method. Highcharts.js line 25. Code 0. Char 55. I wish to implement chart drill down. Hence need to get this working. And IE is standard browser in the company. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used latest highcharts files 2.2.5 and that solved it. Works in IE8. And I feel overall performance is also improved..smooth. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Object doesnt support this property or method
```

This is the Javascript error generated mostly in IE.

Always check for extra comma,single quote in your code when you encounter such JS error.

I can see such one in your code snippet.

```
var seriesOptions = {
                    name: 'chart',
                    data: [],                       

                };
```

This should be

```
var seriesOptions = {
                        name: 'chart',
                        data: []                       

                    };
```

Firefox ignores such error but IE does not let you go. :)