# Highcharts 3D Column --- click event doesn't respond on IE11

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I have tried to attach a `click` event to a Highcharts 3D column using these options:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0.35,
        depth: 25,
        events: {
            click: function() {
                alert("HI")
            }
        }
},
```

This works fine on Chrome: when I click on the column, I see an alert box.

But with Internet Explorer, it doesn't work. When I click on the column in IE11, I don't see an alert box.

Why doesn't the alert box appear in IE11?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742284/highcharts-column-point-click

Comment: I use Highcharts JS v5.0.2 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are there any messages in the Javascript console?

Comment: Don't have any messages.I really appreciate with your help. May be IE11 doesn't support ?

Comment: I tried to recreate the issue on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jsL8j7cj/ In this fiddle, does click event work for you?

Comment: It's working. Thanks for your help RJHunter. ^^